# Get a number with exactly x digits from string

Tags: c#, regex, string, match, digit

im looking for a regex pattern, which matches a number with a length of exactly x (say x is 2-4) and nothing else.

Examples:

`"foo.bar 123 456789"`, `"foo.bar 456789 123"`, `" 123"`, `"foo.bar123 "` has to match only "123"

So. Only digits, no spaces, letters or other stuff.

How do I have to do it?

EDIT: I want to use the Regex.Matches() function in c# to extract this 2-4 digit number and use it in additional code.

Comment: how about `\d{2,4}`? What are you using the run the regex?

Comment: The solution is going to vary based on the regular expression implementation you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any pattern followed by a `{m,n}` allows the pattern to occur m to n times. So in your case `\d{m,n}` for required values of m and n. If it has to be exactly an integer, use`\d{m}`

If you want to match 123 in x123y and not in 1234, use `\d{3}(?=\D|$)(?<=(\D|^)\d{3})`

It has a look ahead to ensure the character following the 3 digits is a non-digitornothing at all and a look behind to ensure that the character before the 3 digits is a non-digit or nothing at all.

Comment: Like Naveed S said, if you want to match a number that is exactly n digits long then you need to use
    \d{n}
In the examples you provided though, \d{n,m} will work as the first number it matches in each of those examples will be 123

Play around with this site to test your regex
http://www.regexplanet.com/

Comment: I've added another example to make my wish clearer. \d{n} also matches 456 and 789, when n = 3.

Comment: @MarcoFrost My second regex matches 3 digits if they are not surrounded by any digit. is it what you require?

Comment: @NaveedS That looks really great! Your second regex is perfect. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with basic RegEx:

`\b(\d\d\d)\b` or `\b(\d{3})\b` - for matching a number with exactly 3 digits

If you want variable digits: `\b(\d{2,4})\b` ([explained demo here](http://regex101.com/r/kS2qJ9))
If you want to capture matches next to words: `\D(\d{2,4})\D` ([explained demo here](http://regex101.com/r/lC0gX7))

`\b` is a word boundary (does not match anything, it's a zero-match character)
`\d` matches only digits
`\D` matches any character that is NOT a digit
`()` everything in round brackets will capture a match